# Full text search doesn't find anything when query has accents

Tags: postgresql, ecto

I have these words: "Fábrica, mágico" that full text search is not returning although the rest is working properly.
My code is (using Elixir lang):

```
def search(query, search_term) do
    (from u in query,
    where: fragment("(to_tsvector('portuguese', ?) || to_tsvector(coalesce('portuguese', ?))) @@ plainto_tsquery('portuguese', ?)", 
                    u.name, u.desc, ^search_term),
    order_by: fragment("ts_rank((to_tsvector('portuguese', ?) || to_tsvector(coalesce('portuguese', ?))), plainto_tsquery('portuguese', ?)) DESC",
                    u.name, u.desc, ^search_term))
  end
```

How to solve this?

Comment: If you want the accents to be ignored: Consider using a dictionary with [`unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/unaccent.html)

Comment: Otherwise, write down the definition of your  'portuguese' configuration. Check: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-psql.html

Comment: I installed unaccented but it is not returning those results. Do I need to configure something else? I can see in my terminal that the extension is installed:                         ` List of installed extensions
   Name   | Version |   Schema   |                 Description                 
----------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------
 plpgsql  | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 unaccent | 1.1     | public     | text search dictionary that removes accents
(2 rows)`

Comment: I also passed this configuration to psql: ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY unaccent (RULES='unaccent');

Comment: Are you sure these words occur in your document? `select to_tsvector('portuguese', 'Fábrica, mágico') @@ plainto_tsquery('portuguese', 'Fábrica, mágico')` returns `true` to me.

Comment: Yes, 100%. There must be some configuration missing because I run in my terminal and db: `select to_tsvector('portuguese', 'Fábrica, mágico') @@ plainto_tsquery('portuguese', 'Fábrica, mágico')` and nothing returns...